# How to save while exiting in middle of game (NBA 2K19 on PC)

Tags: pc, nba2k19

I have NBA 2K19 on PC, and I like playing in "Play Now" mode (not MyCareer or MyLeague or anything else).

If I'm playing a game but get interrupted and can't finish playing right now and don't want to leave the game program running, **how can I save the same** so that I can exit the program, come back later, and open and resume that game?

It was possible on Xbox360 NBA 2K14, so I assume it's possible here, but I haven't figured it out.

As you can see in the screenshots, there isn't a clear option for saving.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save and quit play now because they don't count as one of your own files such as my career, my league... It is counted a quick match that doesn't affect your stats. I have a PS4 and I have the same problem, sometimes I have to quit in 4th quarter and I can't cause i'm winning and I don't want to just quit, so I put the PS4 on rest mode to continue later. But other than that I don't think there is a way to save before quiting.